# Find the difference between event timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains columns event timestamp for every event. How can I find the difference between the two eventtimestap?

For example

```
eevnt timestamp    | eventname
2021-08-26 0:01:46 |gave maths test
2021-08-26 0:17:17 |gave physics test
2021-08-26 0:21:47 |gave chem test
2021-08-26 0:28:58 |gave bio test
```

Here I want to find the time difference between two rows.

Comment: `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, timestamp, LAG(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp))`

Comment: Which MYSQL version are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.